# How does boarding by face-scanning work?

Tags: airport-security

Recently, when boarding from MUC to ATH, the gate agent told us that no identification documents or boarding passes were needed. Instead, we boarded by having our face scanned by a camera mounted on the boarding gate. How does this system work? Where does the face image used for identification come from? I don't think it could come from the passport's biometric data, because this flight operates within the EU Shengen area, so people can travel without a passport.

Comment: At some point you must have checked in and used your boarding card (paper or virtual) to pass through a barrier to get airside. You were probably photographed then. This can then be compared with the one at the gate. Not putting this as an answer as not sure what the system is at MUC but there has in the past been something similar at Manchester (UK) where domestic and international shared a lounge and it stopped you going to the wrong block of gates.

Comment: For it to work for everybody I would think this would happen at security: scan boarding pass, get face scanned at the same time? Don't know if ID is required for Schengen flights from Germany.

Comment: I was transiting through MUC, and I can't remember going through security in MUC. For this to work all airports feeding MUC would have to photograph people at security and share the photos with them. It's very puzzling.

Comment: This may be part of the Star Alliance Biometrics program  https://www.munich-airport.com/touchless-travel-10097864. However, I can't recall registering for it. I don't even have the Lufthansa app, which appears to be required for registration.

Comment: Was this applied to all passengers, or only some of them?

Comment: Surprisingly it was applied to all passengers. There was a gate staffed by an attendant, but we weren't told that only those who satisfied a particular condition could pass through the camera gate.

Comment: @DiomidisSpinellis Maybe it's the other way around: those who get rejected by the camera gate must go to the staffed gate?

Comment: @Johnnyjanko This could be the case. However, I didn't see many people having a problem going through.  I doubt all these were registered to the Star Alliance Biometrics problem. (I for one wasn't.)

Comment: Did you pass through an automated gate before getting to security? Did you have to show your boarding pass QR code to open that gate? I believe that was the moment your face was photographed.

Comment: @Johnnyjanko I passed through a gate with my boarding pass in the US before the security check.  I can't remember seeing a camera there. I also doubt that the system depends on having an infrastructure to photograph passengers at security checks around the world.

Comment: @DiomidisSpinellis oh, so your journey didn't start in MUC, but you flew from the US? In that case, you had to enter the Schengen Area in MUC. Could it be that your face was photographed / filmed there, at the passport check?

Comment: @Johnnyjanko Yes, I passed through an electronic checkpoint that had a camera. If this photo was used it's interesting that the border agency passed the photographs to the the airport for facilitating boarding control.